# Does Element.setAttribute trigger reflow?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, repaint, reflow

I started learning about the inner working of browsers and came across [reflow / repaint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Introduction_to_Layout_in_Mozilla) mechanism (and [how it applies to React](https://medium.com/@gethylgeorge/how-virtual-dom-and-diffing-works-in-react-6fc805f9f84e), but I don't want to digress).

In general, I think anything that makes browsers compute values/ visible changes will trigger reflow/ repaint.

However, I can't wrap my head around [`Element.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute). Does it trigger reflow/ repaint in Chrome? What is the most efficient way to update multiple element attributes in dom tree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, I can't wrap my head around Element.setAttribute. Does it
>   trigger reflow/ repaint in Chrome?

`setAttribute` has no direct relationship to repaint/reflow. It depends on what attribute you set and what kind of element you set it. If you change the `value` of a checkbox, no repaint or reflow will occur, but if you change the `value` of a `<input type="button">`, then a repaint and reflow will occur.

> What is the most efficient way to update multiple element attributes
>   in dom tree?

"Most efficient" is hard to answer because each browser can be optimized to carry out tasks at different paces. But, generally speaking, you can follow these guidelines:

1. Never update the DOM from within a loop as each iteration of the
   loop can cause a repaint/reflow.

   - Instead, you can build up a string of HTML and, when the loop is
     complete, inject the string one time and get all the updates.
   - You can also create and work with elements that have not been added to the DOM tree yet and exist only in memory. Then, you can place those elements in a single container that, itself, is not part of the DOM yet. Finally, you can add the container to the DOM and take the repaint/reflow hit just once.
2. If you are doing many CSS manipulations, and are experiencing performance issues, you may want to look at the [will-change CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change), which can improve performance.

There are many resources available to learn how to reduce the performance hits:

- http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/
- https://www.sitepoint.com/10-ways-minimize-reflows-improve-performance/